# Replace HTML in div when link is clicked

Tags: jquery

Here is my scenario, a ul list with a "holder" div that has HTML in it. I would like to have the ul list have links that when the user clicks should populate the holder div. I have some experience with Jquery but not much. I am able to replace it once but wanted to be able to replace the "holder" div with different blocks of HTML. What I want is the holder div to be populated with the corresponding package HTML.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Package 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Package 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Package 3 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="holder">
    <p>replace this text here<p>
</div>

<div>
    Package 1 HTML
</div>
<div>
    Package 2 HTML
</div>
<div>
    Package 3 HTML
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {      
        $("li a").click(function() {
             $("div.holder").text($(this).next().text());
             return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What html should be in the holder?

Comment: The HTML will be a few divs with text blocks and buttons. Basically the UL list would have a name of the "package" with the "holder" div having a description of the clicked package.

Comment: Sorry I may have been unclear. I have edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically looking for this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $("li a").click(function() {
         //get the index of li element
         var index = $(this).parent().index();

         //get the required div from where to get the content
         var $requiredDiv = $(this)
                            .cloest('ul')
                            .nextAll('div:gt(0)')
                            .eq(index); 

         $("div.holder").html($requiredDiv.html());

         return false;
    });
});
```

`nextAll(selector)` gets all following siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

Comment: I think that is what I do need. One last question, I want the "Package HTML" blocks to be hidden and only shown when the correct li is clicked. Should I use .hide() to hide the package HTML divs?

Comment: Yes, hide them by default. I would suggest you to give those Package HTML divs some class and hide them through styles. If you give classes to these divs your code can be simplified too.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but my how do I get your example to work on say a div that isn't right under the ul list? For example if I have the holder div and package divs in another section of the site? It seems when I remove the holder div and package divs in another section of the site, it no longer works. Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: If you rearrange the markup structure then offcourse the selectors will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the .next() is supposed to be doing. Does it not do what you want without it?

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $("li a").click(function() {
         $("div.holder").text($(this).text());
         return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `html()`. This is what you want to do if I understand correctly:

```
$('li').find('a').click(function(e) {
    var output = '<p>'+ $(this).text() +'</p>';
    $('.holder').append(output);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```